# Word for the sadness you feel when something so wholesome it makes you want to cry

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the kind of heartbreak/ache you feel when something is so wholesome or kind it makes you want to cry?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I suspect you mean poignant

Comment: Please give a specimen sentence with a gap where the word would fit.

Comment: Leaning more toward tears of joy or tears of sadness? In my answer below I had assumed you meant cry ["tears of happiness"] because the opposite kind of crying would seem obviously inappropriate in response to something "so wholesome" or "so kind"

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to say you found a behavior or story to be [touching](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touching).

> capable of arousing emotions of tenderness or compassion

This can be used of genuinely sad things as well, but it works with and is often used for being emotionally moved by good things as well.

Examples

[(IJD)](http://www.ijdesign.org/index.php/IJDesign/article/view/694/298)

> One speaks of a story, of a letter, which are *touching*. “I am *touched by your attention*”.

[(NIH)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29382255/)

> Warm and touching tears: tearful individuals are perceived as warmer because we assume they feel moved and *touched*

[(Quora)](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-hold-back-my-tears-or-just-cry-for-the-touching-or-sad-moments)

> Should I hold back my tears or just cry, for the *touching* or sad moments?

The first example established that it is used of positive things that produce a tender, sympathetic reaction. The second shows it's association with tears. The third distinguishes it from sadness.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the word *poignant*.  Chambers gives the definition

> touching, moving, exciting pathos; stinging, pricking; sharp; acutely painful; penetrating; pungent; piquant.

and you can have *poignancy* (n) and *poignantly* (adj) too.  *exciting pathos* seems to be exactly what the questioner is asking for.

The OED gives a similar definition and offers examples of the word's use such as

> Poignant memories of his father, whose painful boyhood..rendered him incapable of discussing his past.

> Anne stood under the willows, tasting the poignant sweetness of life when some great dread has been removed from it.

and

> There was in this composition such a fusion of sadness and dignity, so poignant an expression of the soul of oppressed and suffering humanity.

Answer (score -1):

**Heartbreaking**

> Producing an intense emotional reaction or response.
>
> *heartbreaking beauty* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heartbreaking)

> Producing a strong emotional reaction: *heartbreaking loveliness*.
> [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/heartbreaking)

---

> A sort of **heartbreaking kindness** grew then between me and Mr. and
> Mrs. Feltner. It grew among us all. It was a kindness of doing
> whatever we could think of that might help or comfort one another.
> [Wendell Berry; *Hannah Coulter*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hannah_Coulter/KNsREAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=heartbreaking%20kindness&pg=PT43&printsec=frontcover)

> I shall advance, I said. But he laughed again, with **hearbreaking**
> kindness, and said gaily... [Storm Jameson; *Journey from the North,
> Vol. 1*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journey_from_the_North_Volume_1/RuiCs3P0sikC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=heartbreaking%20kindness&pg=PT34&printsec=frontcover)

> We watch his **heartbreaking** kindness and intense blue eyes as he
> interacts with mothers and their babies. [J. W. Scott; *Entwined*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Entwined/mvZADAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=heartbreaking%20kindness&pg=PA77&printsec=frontcover)

> With a **heartbreaking** gentleness, she said, 'I'm ... not allowed to
> go out into the city. People would...Tell me what it's like, far away?' [Mary Gentle; *Ilario*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ilario/Jo01AgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=heartbreaking%20gentleness&pg=PT91&printsec=frontcover)

> After His betrayal He met Peter with what **heartbreaking** gentleness
> unmixed with reproof! [Frank Crane; "Moral Ozone" in *Association
> Men*, Vol. 32](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Association_Men/Fn8zAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=heartbreaking%20gentleness&pg=PA391&printsec=frontcover) (1906)

> With **heartbreaking** gentleness Cole touched the blossom , its cool
> , slightly damp pressure like a tiny mouth meeting his finger
> [Elizabeth Hand; *Twelve Monkeys*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Twelve_Monkeys/9k9n-i4LnH8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=heartbreaking%20gentleness&dq=heartbreaking%20gentleness&printsec=frontcover)

> This beauty of mess and ephemerality is in part what Tillmans
> describes: he has a **heartbreaking** fondness for the moment that
> will inevitably vanish, and fanatically attempts to record just how
> lovely, how special and how unrepeatable it is. [Gilda Williams; *How
> to Write About Contemporary Art*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_to_Write_About_Contemporary_Art/Lwc7CwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=heartbreaking%20fondness&pg=PT74&printsec=frontcover)